# Creating Multiple Tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create multiple tables (more than 100 tables) in one go. I am trying to write a script using loop such as for loop for generating as many tables as I want. I am new in PostgreSQL. I would be grateful if someone could give me some tips.

Comment: I'd reconsider why you'd want to create more than 100 tables in a database...especially in a loop.  Are you trying to create an identical table for each user or each customer?  Adding a column called 'customer_name' or an customer_id field is a much better choice.

Comment: @Twelfth, you are right. I am trying to create table for each customer and yes, the tables are identical.

Comment: I usually use spreadsheet with simple text concatenation formulas to do such one-time tasks, e.g.: `="create table "&A1&" (a int, b int);"` where in column A you have table names and then you just copy/paste this formula.

Comment: just write a quick python script with a for loop and each iteration of the loop using the PSQL driver to create a table. done!

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

(
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
for j in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
        echo "SET search_path=tmp;"
        echo "CREATE TABLE barf${i}${j}"
        echo " ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY );"
done
done) | psql -U lutsername databasename
```

Comment: IIRC that would be a bash extension. UPDATE: no, it is not. (but hey! I like to be explicit) But _at least_ it would work on systems where ARG_MAX < 100 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My answer here has to be 'dont do it!' and change your architechture.   Create a table called customer and have a customer_id along with some other info.  Create a second table with the columns you want here and a 'customer_id' column to refer to the customer table.  This format will allow you to store in two tables what you are trying to store in 100+ tables.  You want to stardardize your data base design at this stage...otherwise you are setting yourself up for a nightmare in the not too distant future.  Databases are not spreadsheets...

Comment: I do appreciate your suggestion but it is my client's demand. The organization wants to breakdown their tables into per customer.

Comment: @user2711722: that is the most stupid requirement I have ever heard of. If I were you I would refuse to implement such a nonsense. You can still create a single table and create a view that "fakes" the customer specific tables using Twelth' approach

Comment: I'd still make sure they understand the nightmare they are creating here...future administration costs and the bulkiness of this set up will cripple their business later on (this is why your question has a -2 now).  That said, the customer is always right and if they feel like jumping off a cliff tis our duty to throw them off.  Someone will get a contract to clean this up eventually.  You can loop this with dynamic SQL (security loophole, but I get the feeling your client won't care).  My preference though will be as Tomas Greif said, use a spreadsheet to mass make these table creates.

Comment: To repeat horse with no name...i'd rethink my last comment and refuse to implement, even walk off the job if needed...having my name associated with an implement of a database like this isn't worth it.

Comment: As strict/elitist as SO is with users, I'm surprised so many answers are allowed to stay that do not answer the question. If an OP wants know whether it is a good idea, that is a different question, no? An answer that serves nobody is left to stand while "what is the best way to..." questions are tossed after a quick scan. If the goal of SO is low signal to noise, then...